# How to change a models texture pixel color (Godot)

Tags: c#, godot

I am very new to Godot but looking for a hand on how to change a pixel on a models texture. If there is a model in the scene and Raycast from the screen to world point then hit a model at given texture position, how would you change the actual texture at pixel point to lets say red? I am working in mono, so C# other examples are fine. In the long run I am looking to export this texture with the modified color values.

I can provide some sort of example that way it's clear on what i'm trying to achieve.

Unity3D code:

```
         private void FireRay() {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown(controllerInput.FireButtonName)) {
                    Vector3 direction = requiredComponents.RaycastPosition.position - transform.position;
     
                    RaycastHit raycastHit;
     
                    if (Physics.Raycast(requiredComponents.RaycastPosition.position , direction , out raycastHit)) {
                        if (raycastHit.collider.tag != "Billboard") {
                            return;
                        }
     
                        Renderer renderer = raycastHit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
                        Texture2D texture2D = renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
                        Vector2 pCoord = raycastHit.textureCoord;
                        pCoord.x *= texture2D.width;
                        pCoord.y *= texture2D.height;
     
                        Vector2 tiling = renderer.material.mainTextureScale;
                        Color color = texture2D.GetPixel(Mathf.FloorToInt(pCoord.x * tiling.x) , Mathf.FloorToInt(pCoord.y * tiling.y));
     
                        Debug.Log("Picked color : " + color);
                        requiredComponents.CollisionEvents.PixelColor = color;
     
                        if (requiredComponents.CollisionEvents.OnRayHitBillboard != null) {
                            requiredComponents.CollisionEvents.OnRayHitBillboard.Invoke();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: In all honesty, I don't know how to do this in Godot. However, I'm aware of a few Open Source project that do something like this (For example [Bauxitedev/godot-texture-painter](https://github.com/Bauxitedev/godot-texture-painter) and [tomankirilov/VPainter](https://github.com/tomankirilov/VPainter)).

Comment: Here is an idea: make a material that outputs UV, render using that (Material override) to texture (Viewport), and use that to query the UV where you want to paint.